# How to use one variable's name to refer to another variable?

Tags: bash, shell

```
a=2
pt2=3
echo $a
2
echo $pt2
3
```

How can I use

```
echo $pt($a)
```

to print the contents of `pt2`?

An alternative is

```
b=pt$a
echo $b
pt2
echo $[$b]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=2
pt2=3
eval "echo \"\${pt$a}\""

3
```

Alternatively:

```
b=pt$a
eval "echo \"\${$b}\""

3
```

There are other methods:

```
a=2
pt2=3
export "pt$a=$((pt$a + $(echo pt$a)))"
echo $((pt$a))

6
```

`export` can work like `eval` in that way after a fashion with less hazards - but then there's the unexporting them to do later if you must. And `$((`arithmetic=assignment`))` affects the current command in the current shell and therefore can be safer still for immediate variable assignment if the value is numeric.

There's also the shell's `.dot` and `<<HEREDOCS` for twice evaluating a variable assignment:

```
var1=var2 ; . <<HEREDOC /dev/stdin
    $var1=val
HEREDOC

echo $var2

val
```